# ACF Google Maps - Multiple Pins

Tags: google-maps

I'm using ACF Fields plugin and attempting to create a Google Map which shows post locations, but not getting very far - the pins show up in the wrong places, and when I echo out the title of the post in the HTML bubble above the pin, it's always the same post.. but in 3 different places. I only have 2 out of 10 posts with locations at the moment, so I have no idea why 3 places are being shown.. One is in the middle of the ocean as well. However, this is the closest I've come, and I've wasted the whole day trying...

```
<div class="acf-map">
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>

<?php $location = get_field('location_map'); ?>
<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

I'd have thought this would be relatively simple to achieve, but I guess not.. but then I'm far from the best coder in the world :)

If anyone can give me any pointers on this, I'd be most grateful!

Comment: You should wrap that all in an `if ( $wp_query->have_posts() )` so that you don't call `wp_reset_postdata()` if there are no posts found. You should also verify that `$location` is an array and not an error value, and that the keys 'lat' and 'long' actually exist, if either of those assumptions fail you'll get warnings and notices in your error log or on the page

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks for the advice, cheers :)

What I know is that the fields exist and I can echo out longitude and latitude in the loop with the rest of the post data (title, etc).

I'm just stuck as to how I get that data from there into a <div> at the top of the page where the map is. This is essentially a property website, which may give you an idea as to what I'm trying to pull off.

Hope how I described my issue made sense :)

Comment: You shouldn't assume, and should always check, what if `$location['lat']` contains `"><script>dangerous_javascript();</script><span data="`? You should do some debugging and show us exactly what the contents of `$location` is, as well as an if statement with an `else` case so we can see when no posts were found. Lets ignore what *should* and *shouldn't*, if things were as they should, you wouldn't have opened this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved this in the following [website](http://cascoparking.com)

check the "Ubicación" bock. I did this using ACF Pro (5.0). Im sharing you the code you need in order to implement this. Hope this is what you are looking for (there are a few extra fields that are not needed).

```
    <?php 

    $image = get_field('location_background_image', 'option');
    $size = 'background';
    $location_background_image_url = $image['sizes'][ $size ];

    ?>

    <section id="location" class="location-section" style="<?php if( get_field('location_background_color','option') ): ?>background-color:<?php the_field('location_background_color','options'); ?>;<?php endif; ?><?php if( get_field('location_background_image','option') ): ?>background-image:url(<?php echo $location_background_image_url; ?>); background-size:cover;<?php endif; ?>">

        <div class="container scrollpoint sp-effect3">

          <?php if( get_field('location_title','option') ): ?><h1 class="text-center"><?php the_field('location_title','options'); ?></h1><?php endif; ?>

          <?php if( get_field('location_description','option') ): ?>

              <div id="location-description" class="text-center"><?php the_field('location_description','options'); ?></div>

          <?php endif; ?>

            <style type="text/css">

            .acf-map {
              width: 100%;
              height: 400px;
              border: #ccc solid 1px;
              margin: 40px 0;
            }

            </style>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

            <?php if( have_rows('locations','options') ): ?>
              <div class="acf-map">
                <?php while ( have_rows('locations','options') ) : the_row(); 

                  $location = get_sub_field('location');

                  ?>
                  <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
                    <h4><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('description'); ?></p>
                  </div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div> <!-- .container -->

    </section> <!-- section#location -->

    <div class="section-divider blue">

      <a class="scroll" href="#responsability"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x"></i></a>

    </div> <!-- .section-divider blue -->
```

Comment: @tom I don't suppose you're much of an ACF user - I know what's contained in $location - longitude, latitude and address. Anyhow, appreciate your input, cheers!

Comment: Johann - I think I'll be going down this route. It looks like you used a repeater field for this, which had crossed my mind to use, so will give it a go this way :)